# How to define exception route for laravel global filter?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run a filter that check if application is installed or not, before running any route except installation related routes, cause it would cause an infinite redirect loop.

here is what I was supposed to do:

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    if (!User::isInstalled()) {
        return Redirect::to_route('install'); // infinite redirect loop
    }
});
```

Is there any way to add exception to this filter? or any way to check that currently witch route is running?
any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method from [laravel api, Laravel\Routing\Route](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Routing.Route.html#_is) that could be a solution

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    if ( ! Application::isInstalled() && ! URI::is('install*') ) {
        return Redirect::to_route('install');
    }
});
```

but I think they should be better way to force some routes to not use before filter.
thanks to [bstrahija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025907/bstrahija)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Route::filter('before', function()
{
    if ( ! User::isInstalled() and Request::segment(1) !== 'install') {
        return Redirect::to_route('install');
    }
});
```