# Laravel 4 : Redirection loop with authentification filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a infinite redirection loop with the authentification filter in Laravel.

In my route.php, I have :

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){
Route::resource('administrator', 'AdministratorController');
});
```

Here is my controller :

```
<?php

class AdministratorController extends BaseController {

   protected $layout = "layouts.administrator";

   public function __construct() {
     $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => 'getLogin'));
     //$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
   }

   public function getLogin() {

      $this->layout->content = View::make('administrator.login');

   }
   public function getDashboard() {

      $this->layout->content = View::make('administrator.dashboard');

   }
}
```

And my filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('administrator/login');
});
```

I put a exception in my controller constructor but the filter auth happens before. So, what is the best way to except the login URI ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define exception route for laravel global filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702547/how-to-define-exception-route-for-laravel-global-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Request::segment(2) != 'login' && Auth::guest()) 
    {
        return Redirect::guest('administrator/login');
    }
});
```

And here's another way:

```
Route::get('administrator/login', 'AdministratorController@getLogin');

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){
    Route::resource('administrator', 'AdministratorController');
});
```

The first route will catch request and route to the getLogin function before the filtered group.

Comment: It doesn't work. The other routes do not work anymore with adding this route

Comment: I realized i had a typo in there, did you catch that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a resourceful controller (by using Route::resource()), then your method names are wrong. Please see here for the Laravel documentation on resourceful controllers: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

However, if you're trying to create a *RESTful* controller (which it seems like you're trying to do, judging by your method names in your controller), then you would use Route::controller().

If you are indeed going with the second option, then you can do specify a route name for the login method by doing something like this:

```
Route::controller('administrator', 'AdministratorController', ['getLogin' => 'admin.login']);
```

Then, in your filters.php, modify the auth filter as such:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Route::currentRouteName() != 'admin.login') 
    {
        return Redirect::guest('administrator/login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was one of my mistakes ;) I also had the postSignin method in order to make the authentification. I will put my complete code in a new answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Routes.php

```
Route::controller('administrator', 'AdministratorController');
```

filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
if (Auth::guest())
{
    return Redirect::guest('administrator/login');
}
});
```

AdministratorController.php

```
<?php

class AdministratorController extends BaseController {

protected $layout = "layouts.administrator";

public function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('getLogin', 'postSignin')));
    //$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
}

public function getDashboard() {

    $this->layout->content = View::make('administrator.dashboard');
}

public function getLogin() {

    $this->layout->content = View::make('administrator.login');

}

public function postSignin() {

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')))) {
        return Redirect::to('administrator/dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('administrator/login')
                        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
}
}
```

With this configuration, it is working ! Thanks for your help